# Does CloudFront support versioned origins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a versioned S3 bucket as my origin. Is this the correct format for accessing a specific version of an object from CloudFront?

http://example.cloudfront.net/files/file.pdf?verisonId=[id]

It is ignoring versionId and always serving the head object.

My S3 Bucket Policy allows the following actions for CloudFront:

```
s3:GetObjectVersion

s3:GetObject
```

I've searched and searched but can't seem to find any documentation on this. How do I specify a versionId in a CloudFront URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. In CloudFront go to Distributions > Behaviors. Set "Forward Query Strings" to Yes. This will allow CloudFront to pass versionId to S3 and cache the correct version.

Note that you also only need the `s3:GetObject` bucket policy action to make this work.

Comment: wait... you don't need `s3:GetObjectVersion`?

Comment: Surprisingly no. I'm currently running with only `s3:GetObject` and versioning is working as expected.

Comment: I'll see if I can duplicate that.  It definitely seems unexpected.